# How to use opengl in static lib?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to create a static shader library with OpenGL.
I want it to be as portable as possible (Windows Linus Android ...).
For this propose i made a header what includes gl and glext:
OpenGL.hpp

```
...
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#if defined(OS_WINDOWS)

    #ifdef _MSC_VER
        #include <windows.h>
    #endif

    #include <GL/gl.h>
    #include <GL/glext.h>

#elif defined(OS_LINUX)

    #include <GL/gl.h>
    #include <GL/glext.h>
...
```

And Shader.hpp

```
...
class Shader
{
    unsigned int m_id;
public:
    Shader();
    ...
};
...
```

And Shader.cpp

```
...
#include <Shader.hpp>
#include <OpenGL.hpp>
Shader::Shader()
{
    m_id = glCreateProgram();
    ...
}
...
```

Then complied `Shader.cpp` to `Shader.o` and with `ar` created `libShader.a`.
After that on android i can compile like that:

```
g++ -I ./include -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -L ./lib -o main main.o -lShader -lSDL2 -lGLESv1_CM -lGLESv2
```

And it runs flawless.
But on windows when i link

```
g++ -L ./lib -o main.exe main.o -lShader -lSDL2 -lglew32 -lopengl32 -lglu32
```

G++ gives `lib\libShader.a(Shader.o):Shader.cpp undefined reference to glCreateProgram@8`
error.
On windows main.cpp looks like this:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <Shader.hpp>
...
int main()
{
    Shader shader1;
    ...
    GLuint test_id_for_main = glCreateProgram();
    ...
}
...
```

The wierd thing is `test_id_for_main` works (if i comment out the Shader-s) without link error.
What did i do incorrectly on windows?

Comment: Are you linking GLEW statically? [Try adding `-DGLEW_STATIC`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384510/glew-linker-errors-undefined-reference-to-glewbindvertexarray).

Comment: As i can use any glew functionality in main.cpp i don't think that would the problem.

Comment: Tried it and still getting the same errors

Comment: Also be sure to link to `glew32s` (the `s` at the end is for "static").

Comment: Done, still not working.

Comment: Are you compiling `main.exe` as 32-bit (rather than 64-bit)?

Comment: As 32-bit (i have WinXP).

Comment: I really don't -get it. You only include GL.h and glext.h, and on Windows, you use glew, but on Linux, you don't (but use GLES instead, where those headers are wrong)? How does your extension handling actually work? And how do you switch between ES and desktop GL?

Comment: Not linux but android so GLES is valid.
I switch between them by using different main.cpp.

Comment: You cannot do it that way. When yopu compile your static library, you will have to use GLEW on windows, with the GLEW includes, since these declare the function pointers for all the GL functions. Just using GLEW in the main.o object file will not going to help you there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own OpenGL headers and loading the functions with wgl/glx/dlopen