# Undefined reference when using glew and mingw?

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, glew

I am using Eclipse, I had originally downloaded the binary from the website until someone pointed out that I needed to build it from source to make it work with mingw, so I did and I got these files: **glew32.dll**, **libglew32.a**, and **libglew32.dll.a**

I dropped the **glew32.dll** into the debug folder, and linked the libraries but it did not work.

The weird part: `GLenum status = glewInit();` works but `glClearColor`and `glClear` do not work and I get a **undefined reference to** error when I try to call them.

Please see these screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfkrG.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg8VR.jpg

**C++.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "classHeaders\display.h"
#include "GL\glew.h"


int main(int argv, char** args){
  display x(800,600,"something");

  while(!x.isClosed()){
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.15f,0.3f,1.0f); //undefined reference to ERROR here
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //undefined reference to ERROR here
    x.Update();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**display.cpp**

```
#include "classHeaders\display.h"
#include "GL\glew.h"
#include <iostream>
display::display(int width, int height, const std::string& title){

     SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

     SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE,8);
     SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE,8);
     SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE,8);
     SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE,8);
     SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE,32);
     SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER,1);

     m_window = SDL_CreateWindow(title.c_str(),SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,width,height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

     m_glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(m_window);

     GLenum status = glewInit(); //NO ERRORS OCCUR

     if(status != GLEW_OK){
         std::cerr << "glew failed to initialize" << std::endl;
     }

     m_isClosed = false;
}

display::~display(){
     SDL_GL_DeleteContext(m_glContext);
     SDL_DestroyWindow(m_window);
     SDL_Quit();
}

bool display::isClosed(){
     return m_isClosed;
}

void display::Update(){
     SDL_GL_SwapWindow(m_window);
     SDL_Event e;

    while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)){
        if(e.type == SDL_QUIT){
           m_isClosed = true;
         }
    }
}
```

**display.h**

```
#ifndef DISPLAY_H_
#define DISPLAY_H_

#include <string>
#include "SDL2\SDL.h"
#undef main /*need to put this in or else it gives me "undefined reference to WinMain" ERROR*/

class display{

    public:
        display(int width, int height, const std::string& title);
        void Update();
        bool isClosed();
        virtual ~display();

    private:
        display(const display& other){}
        display& operator=(const display& other){}
        SDL_Window* m_window;
        SDL_GLContext m_glContext;
        bool m_isClosed;

  };

  #endif /* DISPLAY_H_ */
```

Comment: I'm not sure how else to ask this. It's short and to the point. Also if you could help me wirh this problem I would appreciate it.

Comment: It means that when I call them they do not work,  I get a "undefined reference to" error which is weird since 'glewInit();' works. Like how is it able to call 'glewInit():' but not 'glClear'?

Comment: Basically it gives me "undefined reference to" errors on the lines where I called the functions. But when I call the 'glewInIt():' function it doesn't give me a "undefined reference to" error. They all the 3 functions mentioned in the post belong to 'glew' so how is it that only 1 works but I get "undefined reference" for the others?

Comment: Are glew libs and your app compiled with the same compiler and same target (32/64 bits)? I recomend not using pre-build glew lib, but either build it on your own or add the source as any other file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set up [*GLEW*](http://glew.sourceforge.net/), a current [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) is needed (see [Creating an OpenGL Context (WGL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL)) for more information).

### Create OpenGL context and window

A [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) and a window can easily created by [*SDL*](https://wiki.libsdl.org/), [*GLFW*](http://www.glfw.org/) or [*GLUT*](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) (see [Initializing GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html) for more information).

#### Initilize  [*SDL*](https://wiki.libsdl.org/)

If you are using [*SDL*](https://wiki.libsdl.org/) you have to create the window and you have to create the OpenGL context.

```
SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(""OGL window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL );
SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext( window );
```

Note, you should check for errors with [`SDL_GetError`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError).

The OpenGL context has to become the current context before you use it. Use [`SDL_GL_MakeCurrent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_MakeCurrent) therefor.

```
SDL_GL_MakeCurrent( window, glContext );
```

#### Initilize [*GLUT*](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/)

To set up [*GLUT*](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) you have to use [`glutInit`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node10.html) and can follow the instructions of initializing [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html).

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutCreateWindow("OGL window");
```

#### Initilize [*GLFW*](http://www.glfw.org/)

Note, [`glfwInit`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__init.html#ga317aac130a235ab08c6db0834907d85e) returns `GLFW_TRUE` if succeded:

```
if ( glfwInit() != GLFW_TRUE )
    return;

GLFWwindow *wnd = glfwCreateWindow( width, height, "OGL window", nullptr, nullptr );
if ( wnd == nullptr )
{
    glfwTerminate();
    return;
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent( wnd );
```

After you have created an [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) and you have made it become the current context, you have to initialize [*glew*](http://glew.sourceforge.net/).

### Set up [*GLEW*](http://glew.sourceforge.net/)

**Note that [`glewInit`](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html) returns `GLEW_OK` if succeded**:

```
if ( glewInit() != GLEW_OK )
    return;
```

To link the [*GLEW*](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) library correctly you have to set up proper **preprocessor definitions**:

> On Windows, you also need to define the `GLEW_STATIC` preprocessor token when building a static library or executable, and the `GLEW_BUILD` preprocessor token when building a dll

See also the answer to [GLEW Linker Errors (undefined reference to `__glewBindVertexArray')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384510/glew-linker-errors-undefined-reference-to-glewbindvertexarray)

Comment: I tried something similar using SDL2 but I still get the same error, I put the code up there so maybe you can see something I can't?

Comment: Okay I tried the `SDL_GetError` to see if `SDL_Init` worked and it returned a value of 0 so it did. I tried adding `SDL_GL_MakeCurrent` right after the `m_window` and `m_glContext` and it still gave me the **undefined reference to** error to `glClear` and `glClearColor`. Is this just an Issue with my code? All I need to know if it's my code or the way I have everything set up. If it's just my code I can probably figure it out but if there's something wrong with my set up (the `.a` and `.dll`'s and the linker etc...) then I need to figure that out. Though I'm pretty sure it's my code?

Comment: So there's nothing wrong with what I have? Hmm. Like mentioned "glewInit()" works but "glClear" doesn't. SDL2 also works. So I don't think it's my setup? This is really weird

Comment: I added the GLEW_STATIC pre-processor but it still gave the same error. I'm pretty sure it's my code though so I'll look at the links and try to fix it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: okay so apparently it wasn't my code, it had to do with the linker but I finally fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

So basically to solve this problem you want to download the source from the glew website and compiler it yourself. You use the command prompt to get in the directory of the folder you downloaded and execute these commands **line by line in order:**

**gcc -DGLEW_NO_GLU -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude -DGLEW_BUILD -o src/glew.o -c src/glew.c**

**gcc -nostdlib -shared -Wl,-soname,libglew32.dll -Wl,--out-implib,lib/libglew32.dll.a -o lib/glew32.dll src/glew.o -L/mingw/lib -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32**

and finnally:

**gcc-ar cr lib/libglew32.a src/glew.o** (though the "gcc-" may not be needed, it was for me)

Once you're done with that left click on your project and go to **Properties**, then under **C/C++ Build** go to **settings**, then under **MinGW C++ Linker** click in **Libraries**. Once you're there make sure your **Library search path** is correct (the place where Eclipse looks for your libraries) then in **Libraries** enter these one by one: **glew32 opengl32 glu32 glew32.dll SDL2 SDL2main SDL2_test**

Also when you compiled from source there should be a glew32 with a `.dll` not a `.a` extension in your **lib** folder inside the glew folder you downloaded from the website, drop that in into your debug (where your `.exe` is created). Do the same for the `.dll`**not** the `.dll.a` for **SDL** and also make sure you have your include folders for both **glew** and **SDL** set up under the **GCC C++ Compiler** (also under your settings for the **C/C++ Builder**). It should work now.