# my open gl doesn't work properly?

Tags: c, opengl, glut

i was trying to setup opengl libraries on visual studio 2013 this code for drawing a triangle i don't have error in error list which relate to include files but  it dosen't work 
this is the code:

```
#include<glut.h>

static void redraw();

void main()
{
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100); 
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 300); 
    glutCreateWindow("Application11");
    glutDisplayFunc(redraw);
    glutMainLoop();
}

static void redraw()
{
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2f(0,1);
    glVertex2f(0.5,0);
    glVertex2f(0.5,0);
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: 1) You are setting the color *after* the triangle has been drawn. 2) Your second and third vertex are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize the [GLUT](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) library (see [`glutInit`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node10.html)):

Either:

```
int main()
{
    int cnt = 0;
    glutInit(&cnt, NULL);
    .....
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    .....
```

Further 2 points of your triangle are equal. Change it for example to:

```
 glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
 glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
 glVertex2f( 0.0f, 1.0f );
 glVertex2f( 0.5f, 0.0f );
 glVertex2f( 0.5f, 1.0f );
 glEnd();
```

See further [Undefined reference when using glew and mingw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473091/undefined-reference-when-using-glew-and-mingw/45476269#45476269)

Comment: yes it was initializing issue it works right now thank you