# Segmentation fault when calling glGenVertexArrays()?

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I am getting segmentation fault when I call `glGenVertexArrays()`:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>

int main()
{
    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
}
```

Answers to such problem suggest setting `glewExperimental` to true, but this is already set in my code.

Comment: You have to [Create an OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL)), see also [Undefined reference when using glew and mingw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473091/undefined-reference-when-using-glew-and-mingw)

Comment: Thank you. Creating the window solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After verifying that `glewInit()` returned `GLEW_OK` [ask GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html) if the current GL context supports VAOs before attempting to use them via:

- A core version check ([VAOs have been a core feature since GL 3.0](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object)):

  ```
  if(GLEW_VERSION_3_0)
  {
      // do VAO stuff
  }
  ```
- Or by checking for `ARB_vertex_array_object` extension support:

  ```
  if(GLEW_ARB_vertex_array_object)
  {
      // do VAO stuff
  }
  ```

Otherwise if `glewInit()` failed or if VAOs aren't supported then GLEW-declared function pointers like `glGenVertexArrays` will remain NULL and segfault when you try to call them.